# interpolate.splev error: 'Lengths of the first three arguments (x,y,w) must be equal'

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to do a least squares fit using scipy.interpolate in the following way:

```
from scipy import interpolate
xnew = np.arange(min(l_bins), max(l_bins))
list1=l_bins
list1.remove(l_bins[0])
list1.remove(l_bins[-1])
tck = interpolate.splrep(l_bins,l_hits,k=3,task=-1,t=list1)
fnew = interpolate.splev(xnew, tck, der=0)
plt.plot(xnew, fnew, 'b-')
```

When I run the code I get this error:

```
TypeError: Lengths of the first three arguments (x,y,w) must be equal
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Always include the *complete* traceback, so we know which line generated the error.  In this case, I assume it is the call to `splrep`.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be here:

```
list1=l_bins
list1.remove(l_bins[0])
list1.remove(l_bins[-1])
```

When you say `list1=l_bins`, `list1` refers to the *same* object as `l_bins`.  It is not a copy.  So when you remove elements from `list1` in-place with `remove`, you are also modifying `l_bins`.  Here's an example; note that modifying `b` in-place also modifies `a`;

```
In [17]: a = [10, 20, 30]

In [18]: b = a

In [19]: b.remove(10)

In [20]: b
Out[20]: [20, 30]

In [21]: a
Out[21]: [20, 30]
```

To fix this, `list1` should be a *copy* of `l_bins`.  It looks like `l_bins` is a Python list.  In that case, you can say

```
list1 = l_bins[:]
```

It appears, though, that you want to remove the first and last elements of `l_bins` from `list1`.  In that case, you could replace this

```
list1 = l_bins[:]
list1.remove(l_bins[0])
list1.remove(l_bins[-1])
```

with

```
list1 = l_bins[1:-1]
```